# What more can I do to my question to get help?

Tags: support, specific-question, unanswered-questions

I have a question about my Super User post: [Windows 10 Jumplist pinned server items lag?](https://superuser.com/questions/1100772/windows-10-jumplist-pinned-server-items-lag)

I'm quite disappointed that I have had very little response to this question. This is an issue which I am still experiencing and I have not been able to find anything else online which gives me any idea how to resolve it. I've checked out advice on how to improve my question both in help (https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers) and on meta, and have acted accordingly, including editing tags, editing the question and adding updates as I find more information. Possibly my tags are not regarded as being the best but I could not think of any other ones in the circumstances.

I am also under the impression that it is not individual to my computer as (as I mentioned in an update) I have seen the issue reproduced on another PC here.

What further can I do? The issue persists and after a month I have had just 50 views at time of this question, no upvotes (or downvotes), no comments and no answers. I have asked very few questions on the stackexchange network but try to abide by all the guidelines suggested. Can anyone suggest futher tags, additional edits, anything I can do to get some support? Unfortunately as a relative newcomer I have very little reputation and am unable to offer any bounty.

Or am I asking in the wrong forum, in which case could the question be migrated?

I really would appreciate some guidance on this as I would be extremely relieved to get my issue resolved. In the meantime I will continue to update it as and when I have more information to post.

Comment: seems like you're running into a problem which very few have faced. There really isn;t much that you can do, perhaps mention how/where the network files are connected(ie you haven't mentioned how the remote system is connected)

Comment: @Sathya thank you. I will have a look at this on Monday.

Comment: @Sathya When you say the "remote system" are you talking about the server? And what information is relevant to how/where the network files are connected? Our (Linux) server sits in our comms room and is connected via wired LAN - is this the sort of thing I should be including in my question? Sorry, I'm not very intelligent as to network setup or describing how anything is set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed like there was very little further to do to get my question answered, short of posting this question here on Meta. Ultimately @Ramhound offered a bounty, and the question was resolved with the help of @varfirstname.